# error cannot read property name fieldnamefilter of undefined when filter data?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I work on angular 7 app I face error cannot read property name 'fieldnamefilter' of undefined when filter data ?

filter name I get it dynamically based on variable fieldnamefilter

below code is give error on this.fieldnamefilter :

```
  contentBody:any[];
 fieldnamefilter:any;

console.log("data values : " + this.fieldnamefilter ) 
//result is data values : onlineURL on console log

// error display on line below filter data[0].this.fieldnamefilter
this.contentBody = data.filter(item =>item != data[0].this.fieldnamefilter);
```

but if i use it as data[0].onlineURL as below it working ;

```
 //working when use field name direct data[0].onlineURL

this.contentBody = data.filter(item =>item != data[0].onlineURL);
```

data is have datatype any[];
so How to solve this issue ;

**Updated post I try :**

```
console.log(this.fieldnamefilter it give me onlineURL
console.log(data[0][this.fieldnamefilter] it give me N/A
```

Comment: this keyword is reserved reaching class variables/methods, if you have a field called fieldnamefilter inside your objects of data array, you can use it like data[0].fieldnamefilter by removing this in the middle.

Comment: when use field name direct it work but on my case i stored filter name on variable because it not fixed and depend on data exist on database

Comment: so how to use variable name on data[0].variable have filter

Comment: Ok that wasn't clear in the question, if you store a field in that variable, you can use it like this: data[0][this.fieldnamefilter]

Comment: Also using any for types is not a good practice, you should have models for each type, it makes debugging so much easier.

Comment: on console.log it give me  N/A

Comment: console.log("data values" + data[0][this.fieldnamefilter]) it give me N/A

Comment: Ok then there is no data for the field name you store in your variable

Comment: this is not correct if i use data[0].onlineurl it working but if i use console log for [this.fielnamefiter] it give me onlineurl but when using as data[0][this.fieldnamefilter] it give me N/A so how to solve issue

Comment: Sorry that's what I can do at the moment, with the sample you have. I would be happy to help if you can provide a MRE. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: see updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = [{onlineurl: 'asdasd'}, {onlineurl: 'xxxx'}];
const fieldnamefilter = 'onlineurl';
const filteredData = data.filter(entry => entry[fieldnamefilter] === data[0][fieldnamefilter]);
```

This snippet works as intended, so as we can not debug the code without a MRE, I can not tell anything further. If you providea a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in Stackblitz or somewhere, we can help further. Also if your data look different than this please provide a sample.